# Find string in array and return its index

Tags: kotlin

Is there a way to search through a string array and return its index if it is found. Of course I can just iterate through the array and perform the search myself. But I am wondering if there is a more efficient way of doing it. Kotlin has the "contains" method but that returns a boolean. I want the index position instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you need to find specific string's index, then you should use `indexOf()` method. E.g.

```
val index = listOf("a","b","c").indexOf("a")
```

It will return -1 if the string is not found though.